# Objective-C: UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
`[super viewDidLoad];`

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM";
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTime];
NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:dateTime];

if ([dateString isEqual:@"23/06"]) {
    if ([timeString isEqual:@"23:30"]) {
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate = dateTime;
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"It's 11:30 PM 23th June!"];
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }
}
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){

    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge| UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

The notification isn't receiving when time equals string and date.
Please help!

Comment: How does `dateTime` get set?

Comment: NSDate *dateTime;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter; \n After @implementation

Comment: Hmmm, so `dateTime` never gets set? Or do you set it to the current date with `dateTime = [NSDate date];`? If you haven't set it, then that would be the issue. If you have, then the reason why I ask how it gets set is because you are converting it to a string to compare, which might be an issue with locale.

Comment: I set dateTime: dateTime = [NSDate date];, but still not working :/

Comment: I also noticed...did you allocate dateFormatter and timeFormatter? `dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]` and `timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]`. Even though you declared instance variables by putting them after `@implementation`, you still need to create the objects themselves.

Comment: Yea, I allocated these too! but still :/

Comment: This is my sample code: http://www.mediafire.com/download/21042w7e0c5xfhn/UILocalNotification+Demo.zip

Comment: Oh, I just realized what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue with this (aside from using strings to compare dates) is that viewDidLoad gets called only once in this application. Because you are only scheduling the local notification when the current date is 11:30, it will never get called, since you also set the fireDate to the same exact time.

The thing is, local notifications get scheduled prior to the event. In fact, you should set dateTime to the desired schedule time and then set the local notification.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setYear:2016];
[dateComponents setMonth:6];
[dateComponents setDay:23];
[dateComponents setHour:23];
[dateComponents setMinute:30];

dateTime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = dateTime;
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"It's 11:30 PM 23th June!"];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Based on your uploaded code, it looks like you are going to be grabbing the date from the datePicker, so eventually, you will move the `UILocalNotification` portion to the button method and use `[datePicker date]` as the `fireDate`. Meaning, you can ignore the `dateComponents` part.

Comment: I'm so thanks full for wasting your time! Thanks allot! but one more thing... How to set the year for every year, i mean repeating this notification every year at 23/june/ time: 23:30? (not just 2016)

Comment: Oh, it's no trouble! Local notifications have a `repeatInterval` property that you can set to a calendar unit (one of which is year).